# how to put functions inside of widgets

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to put my own function in a widget but it doesn't run.  I want to use it everywhere within the widget.

If I could see an example,that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few way to run a function in widgets:

**option 1 - ShortCodes**

You can create a custom shortcode and run that function by entering the shortcode into a simple text widget:

```
//this is to make sure WordPress renders the shortcodes in a text widget
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

add_shortcode('my_short_code','my_function');

function my_function(){
  //do whatever you want
}
```

and then simply add `[my_short_code]` to any text widget to run your function.

**Option 2 Plugins**

You can use one of the many plugins out there that let you run php in a widget like:

- [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/)
- [WP Sidebar Essential](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-sidebar-essential/)
- [PHP-Widgetify](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-widgetify/)

**Option 3 Custom Widgets**

The last way is to write your own widget using the very simple [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)